# ASP.net Identity - Login/Add User Duplicate Database

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Have this web-forms using ASP.Net Identity register form,

problem occurs each time I try to login / register new user, error: "Cannot create file 'D:\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf' because it already exists."

Seems like the Identity system try to create new DataBase every time, instead of using the created one at the first user creation.

***From web.config:***

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="db_mainConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="db_mainConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the DatabaseInitializer strategy being used along with the Asp.net identity providers. If you're using code first then it creates your database automatically based on DatabaseInitializer Strategy specified. This is the reason why the application is creating the database every time you're running the applicaion.

see this article for more details over [DatabaseInitializer](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm).

You can get rid of this problem by [enabling database migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621). Migrations allows you to only propagate the changes in the schema to database rather than droping and creating database every time new changes in the Models are detected.

Comment: Re-Installing EF, Thanks :)